# Python - Remover elementos de uma lista

Tags: python, csv, dataset

eu possuo uma lista em Python e desejo substituir determinados elementos nela, já tente usar o modo replace que eu achei na documentação, mas não obtive sucesso, pois ele não pode ser usado em listas.

Possuo uma lista da seguinte maneira.

```
Mylist = ['Ford"~"Fiat"~"Ka"~"Palio']
```

Essa lista é composta por um único elemento, utilizando a função len(linha) ele me retorna o valor 1.

Eu preciso tratar essa linha para sair da seguinte maneira.

```
NewList= ['Ford','Fiat','Ka','Palio']
```

Estou tentando de varias formas e não estou conseguindo obter o resultado esperado.

Meu código:

```
encoding='utf-8'

import csv

NewMatriz = []


ficheiro = open('C:\\Users\\asus\\Documents\\models.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding="utf8")
reader = csv.reader(ficheiro)


for item in reader:
    NewMatriz.append(item.replace('"','').split('~'))
```

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo de `models.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso, é remover as aspas duplas com a função **replace** e transformar a string em um array com a função **split** com base no (~):

```
#Lista simples
Mylist = ['Ford"~"Fiat"~"Ka"~"Palio']

NewList = Mylist[0].replace('"','').split('~')

print(NewList)

#Lista matriz

#Com loop
NewMatriz = []

for item in Mylist:
  NewMatriz.append(item.replace('"','').split('~'))

print(NewMatriz)

#Com map/lambda
NewMapList = []

NewMapList = map(lambda x: x.replace('"','').split('~'), Mylist)
print(list(NewMapList))
```

Nos demais exemplos, criei uma dentro de outra, apenas para exemplificar que podem existir outras formas, porém com resultados um pouco distintos, mas pode ser útil na sua resolução.

---

Trabalhando com o CSV:

```
encoding='utf-8'

import csv

NewMatriz = []

ficheiro = open('C:\\Users\\asus\\Documents\\models.csv', 'r', newline='\n', encoding="utf8")
reader = csv.reader(ficheiro)

for line in reader:
  for item in line:
    NewMatriz.append(item.replace('"','').split('~'))

print(NewMatriz)
```

Comment: Dessa maneira deu certo, porem em quando eu pego esses dados de um csv, ele me retorna a seguinte mensagem 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace''

Comment: Adicionei o código no exemplo

Comment: Coloca o seu CSV também, por favor

Comment: Adicionado, são dados que eu peguei no site da anac, tem mais de 5000 linhas, estou tentando tratar esses dados

Comment: A leitura do CSV é diferente, coloquei um outro exemplo, espero que te ajude.

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado, estava tentando e não estava conseguindo.

Comment: Ótimo, se possível então, por favor, aceita a resposta.

Comment: Feito, só não tinha feito, pois não sabia dessa opção.Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Procura na documentação da csv.reader se tem algum argumento que você pode utilizar para redefinir o separador de campos. 
Eu uso a biblioteca pandas e a função read_csv, que acho bem mais amigável. Nela, você consegue definir o argumento "sep" que identifica na leitura do arquivo qual caracter está sendo utilizado para separar os campos. No seu exemplo, para ser o "~".
Outra possibilidade é que o encoding não está certo. Talvez ele esteja lendo "~" quando na verdade é um ";". Tenta usar encoding "latin" ou "latin1" e veja se o output é diferente.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/246261)

Comment: Na verdade o Eduardo toca num ponto excelente. Se o separador do CSV for corretamente configurado o AP não vai precisar fazer essa gambiarra para substituir as strings. O problema é que a resposta não é muito descritiva, mas dá pra trabalhar nela.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Eduardo, vou pesquisar sobre isso sim

Comment: @AndréFilipe, obrigado pela orientação. Começando agora a de fato participar colaborando. Vou me atentar para isso nas próximas. abs